# Question about $\LaTeX$ generated by Mathematica

Tags: export, latex

I saved a Mathematica Notebook as a `*.tex` file. When compiling in TeXnicCenter I get the an error on the following generated code.

```tex
\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(\(\{0,10,1\}\)\)
\end{doublespace}
```

The error is just: `Bad math environment delimiter`.

Question: How to get rid of the above error? ( Perhaps, this is one for the $\TeX$ group? )

By the way, most of the notebook is readable in the PDF that has been generated despite the error message.

By request.

```
Cell[CellGroupData[{Cell["Isometries", "Section",
 CellChangeTimes->{{3.537693172799428*^9, 3.5376931780345087`*^9}}],

Cell[CellGroupData[{

Cell["Rotation r( c, \[Theta] )", "Subsection",
 CellChangeTimes->{{3.53769767043847*^9, 3.5376976976887302`*^9}}],

Cell[CellGroupData[{

Cell[BoxData[
 RowBox[{
  RowBox[{"r", "[", 
   RowBox[{
    RowBox[{"{", 
     RowBox[{"0", ",", "0"}], "}"}], ",", 
    FractionBox["\[Pi]", "2"]}], "]"}], ".", 
  RowBox[{"{", 
   RowBox[{"10", ",", "0", ",", "1"}], "}"}]}]], "Input",
 CellChangeTimes->{{3.5376977167764263`*^9, 3.537697742754182*^9}, {
  3.537697791774678*^9, 3.5376978287525744`*^9}, {
  3.5376978660254316`*^9, 3.53769787910806*^9}, {3.537697978108968*^9,
   3.53769804034195*^9}, {3.5376984660418816`*^9, 
  3.5376984703793983`*^9}}],

Cell[BoxData[
 RowBox[{"{", 
  RowBox[{"0", ",", "10", ",", "1"}], "}"}]], "Output",
 CellChangeTimes->{
  3.537697802907297*^9, {3.5376978586153617`*^9, 
   3.537697880345572*^9}, {3.537697981996502*^9, 
   3.537697992024061*^9}, 3.53769802411933*^9, 3.537698072699666*^9, 
   3.5376984781344557`*^9, 3.5378633219215155`*^9}]
}, Open  ]]
}, Open  ]]
}, Open  ]]
```

Comment: Can we see the offending line in Mathematica somehow? Either as a Cell expression or perhaps as an image?

Comment: `\(...\)` ... *shudder*

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky - See text of question.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be seeing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The immediate problem with the LaTeX is that \( and \) appear twice.  Thus, the following works fine, assuming the setspace package has been loaded.

```tex
\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(\{0,10,1\}\)
\end{doublespace}
```

Another question, of course, is why this export went wrong and how to change that.  That's hard to say without seeing the Mathematica expression.

Comment: A simple function actually but just below two headings one created with Alt+3 and the other with Alt+5. - Don't waste time on it, I won't either.